# SwingWorker gui repaint

Tags: swing, generics, user-interface, swingworker

Im trying to use the SwingWorker to update my gui without calling repaint().

I want the SwigWorker to update the status of each GridGraphic[i][j] and the have the gui be repsonsive to the changes without calling repaint().

GridGraphic.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridGraphic extends JComponent {

    private int intensity = 0;

    public GridGraphic() {
        //setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        //paints the GridGraphic black
        if (intensity == 0){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        //paints the GridGraphic black with a yellow dot
        else if (intensity == 5){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(3, 3, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        }

    }


    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(10, 10);
    }

    public void setAgent(){
        intensity = 5;
    }

    public void setDefault(){
        intensity = 0;
    }

    public int getIntensity(){
        return intensity;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am no expert on swing, but I do not believe that changing the generic typing of a program can change its runtime behavior in any observable way.

Comment: exact duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930606/swingworker-update-gui-without-calling-repaint. Or same homework?